# Memory Management - How and when to write large objects to disk

Tags: c#, memory-management, virtual-memory

I am working on an application which has potential for a large memory load (>5gb) but has a requirement to run on 32bit and .NET 2 based desktops due to the customer deployment environment. My solution so far has been to use an app-wide data store for these large volume objects, when an object is assigned to the store, the store checks for the total memory usage by the app and if it is getting close to the limit it will start serialising some of the older objects in the store to the user's temp folder, retrieving them back into memory as and when they are needed. This is proving to be decidedly unreliable, as if other objects within the app start using memory, the store has no prompt to clear up and make space. I did look at using weak pointers to hold the in-memory data objects, with them being serialised to disk when they were released, however the objects seemed to be getting released almost immediately, especially in debug, causing a massive performance hit as the app was serialising everything.

Are there any useful patterns/paradigms I should be using to handle this? I have googled extensively but as yet haven't found anything useful.

Comment: What is the kind of data you're dealing with? Why are they as big? Why not generally keeping them on disk or in a database?

Comment: would something like memcached or coherence do what you want?

Comment: I can't specify the exact data, but the datasets we're processing can easily be gigabytes. Typically we are loading around 1gb of data, sourced from disk initially, processed and reprocessed with the intermediate data needing to be available but not an end deliverable. When we cache everything to disk the processing can take a week, in memory takes significantly less, hence wanting to keep the data in memory wherever possible and only writing out the end data deliverable.

Comment: Hi Joe - I'd looked at memcached and coherence, however they seem to be aimed at caching data loaded from disk, as opposed to only writing to disk if memory becomes pressed. Thank you though!

Comment: Do you really need random access to all this data? There are plenty of ways to efficiently deal with large data on disk, going from content indexes to stream-based algorithms such as mergesort. It's likely that leaving memory for Windows to perform file caching is going to yield better performance than trying to swap manually, unless you really know what data you won't need for some time.

Comment: Hi Lucero, thanks for your help. I really do need unforecastable access to this data. I'm trying to avoid the hit of writing any of this data to disk. If I could afford the time to write it to disk, I would simply use standard caching of the data read from disk, re-reading when needed. In many situations, I can run entirely in memory and performance is fantastic, it's only when I exceed the available memory that I need to do something different.

Comment: Empirically, the data which was last accessed the longest ago is the least likely to be needed again. This is a first approximation which does not always hold true but is sufficiently close for the time being.

Answer (score 4):

I thought [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) was supposed to have you covered in this situation?

Anyways, it seems suspect that you really need all 5gb of data in memory at any given moment - you can't possibly be processing all that data at any given time - at least not on what sounds like a consumer PC. You didn't go into detail about your data, but something to me smells like the object itself is poorly designed in the sense that you need the entire set to be in memory to work with it. Have you thought about trying to fragment out your data into more sensible units - and then do some preemptive loading of the data from disk, just before it needs to be processed? You'd essentially be paying a more constant performance trade-off this way, but you'd reduce your current [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29) issue.

Comment: +1: Agreed.  It sounds like you're trying to implement your own paging scheme, which I bet Microsoft have already solved.

Comment: 32bit allows only 2GB (or 3GB in a special Windows configuration) of user addressable memory space. So paging doesn't really solve the question asked.

Comment: @Lucero: That would explain why his app immediately starts "caching". I think my original suggestion of trying to re-visit the structure of the data is really the ultimate answer to the solution. I'll try to clarify this.

Comment: I agree with you. I was just pointing out that paging/virtual memory is not going to solve the issue, because there's something else which needs to be done in order to reduce the amount of actual memory use.

Comment: All - the initial data file is typically around 1gb, with the resulting objects which are being processed averaging in the order of Mb - I have added some more info further up which I will avoid repeating. I apologise that I am constrained on how much I can say, but think of it as needing to converge on a solution through an iterative process, however with the potential to need to retreat to a previous step and take a different route. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you go with [Managing Memory-Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx) and look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366556(VS.85).aspx). In .NET 2.0 you have to use PInvoke to that functions. Since .NET 4.0 you have efficient [built-in functionality](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/salvapatuel/archive/2009/06/08/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net-4.aspx) with [MemoryMappedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx).

Also take a look at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx

You can't store 5GB data in-memory efficiently. You have 2 GB limit *per process* in 32-bit OS and 4 GB limit per 32-bit process in [64-bit Windows-on-Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384249(VS.85).aspx)

So you have choice:

- Go in Google's Chrome way (and FireFox 4) and maintain potions of data between processes. It may be applicable if your application started under 64-bit OS and you have some reasons to keep your app 32-bit. But this is not so easy way. If you don't have 64-bit OS I wonder where you get >5GB RAM?
- If you have 32-bit OS when any solution will be file-based. When you try to keep data  in memory (thru I wonder how you address them in memory under 32-bit and 2 GB per process limit) OS just continuously swap portions of data (memory pages) to disk and restores them again and again when you access it. You incur great performance penalty and you already noticed it (I guessed from description of your problem). The main problem OS can't predict when you need one data and when you want another. So it just trying to do best by reading and writing memory pages on/from disk.

  So you already use disk storage indirecltly in inefficient way, MMFs just give you same solution in efficient and controlled manner.

You can rearchitecture your application to use MMFs and OS will help you in efficient caching. Do the quick test by yourself MMF maybe good enough for your needs.

Anyway I don't see any other solution to work with dataset greater than available RAM other than file-based. And usually better to have direct control on data manipulation especially when such amount of data came and needs to be processed.

Comment: Hi Sentinel - thanks for the suggestion, but that would rely on me writing the data out to disk to be able to memory map the file, I am trying to avoid the CPU/IO hit of serializing this much data to disk if it's not needed.

Comment: +1, this is the correct answer.  There isn't any other place you can shove 5 gigabytes, MMFs make the disk I/O transparent.  Albeit that they are quite incompatible with garbage collection.  A 64-bit operating system is the 200 dollar solution.

Comment: @Hans Passant, thank you. I agree with you about 64-bit OS suggestion thru it maybe not an option for Matt since it requires to upgrade all its customers but he ask about .NET 2.0 so Im not sure he can upgrade.

@Matt Reeve: I'll comment in my answer

Comment: @Hans - I would absolutely love my customers to be able to move to 64-bit. Indeed, we have prototyped this and the problem did go away, however we have a very constrained deployment environment which restricts us to x86 and .NET 2.0.

Comment: @Matt - it is simple economics.  I'd guess this is going to take you at least a month to get it to not completely suck.  Your boss counts your hours at, say, $150 per.  That's 24K.  You can buy a 64-bit box from Dell for about $600.  Ship your code now, include 40 machines to break even.  This is the kind of reasoning that appeals to the bean counters who put up these kind of artificial road blocks.  YMMV.

Comment: @Hans - While I would whole-heartedly agree with you if this was in a pure commercial environment, the deployment environment with my customer is far more constrained, for example the equipment would need to be fully ruggedised. The costs of the kit and the deployment would far far exceed the £24k cost.

Comment: @Matt - do the bean counters carry guns?  Well, worth a shot, good luck with it.

Comment: I had a hunch the OP's customer was gov/mil related!

Answer (score -1):

When you have to store huge loads of data and mantain accessibility, sometimes the most useful solution is to use data store and management system like database. Database (MySQL for example) can store a lots of typical data types and of course binary data too. Maybe you can store your object to database (directly or by programming business object model) and get it when you need to. This solution sometimes can solve many problems with data managing (moving, backup, searching, updating...), and storage (data layer) - and it's location independent - mayby this point of view can help you.